Micro freeze every 10 seconds
I have a micro freeze every 10 seconds as you can see by the glxgears logs:

This micro freeze looks more like CPU or RAM related because the image is freezing but mouse input is not registered during the freeze. I also observed with htop that one xorg process seems to spike the CPU when the freeze occurs.

I also know my computer does not overheat.
I tried switching to zen core instead of the generic ones with these commands:
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damentz/liquorix && sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-image-liquorix-amd64 linux-headers-liquorix-amd64

and ran this command that I thought would be useful sudo cpufreq-set -r -g performance
Here is my hardware:
  CPU - Ryzen 7 5700x3d |
  GPU - rtx 3060 lhr |
  RAM - 32Go 3600Mhz

Running non tested kernel makes it not possible to know what will happen by anyone here.
